# How to create graph using mysql table in shiny?

Tags: mysql, r, plot, graph, shiny

I'm new to R and shiny, so please bear with me if there are syntax or some basic errors.
I'm trying to create a bar graph using mysql table. Table looks like:

```
+--------------+------------------------+--------+
| SerialNumber | EpicName               | Result |
+--------------+------------------------+--------+
|            1 | UnifiedSearch_Pass     |    177 |
|            2 | UnifiedSearch_Fail     |      8 |
|            3 | Settings_Pass          |     57 |
|            4 | Settings_Fail          |      5 |
|            5 | Map_Overview_Pass      |     90 |
|            6 | Map_Overview_Fail      |      6 |
|            7 | Map_Guidance_Pass      |     48 |
|            8 | Map_Guidance_Fail      |      3 |
|            9 | RouteBar_Pass          |     48 |
|           10 | RouteBar_Fail          |      6 |
|           11 | MainMenu_Pass          |    109 |
|           12 | MainMenu_Fail          |     12 |
|           13 | SpeedCameras_Pass      |     17 |
|           14 | SpeedCameras_Fail      |      2 |
|           15 | MapManagement_Pass     |     14 |
|           16 | MapManagement_Fail     |      0 |
|           17 | AccountManagement_Pass |     12 |
|           18 | AccountManagement_Fail |      0 |
|           19 | VoiceManagement_Pass   |     10 |
|           20 | VoiceManagement_Fail   |      0 |
|           21 | Total_Automated_Tests  |    624 |
|           22 | Total_Pass             |    582 |
|           23 | Total_Fail             |     42 |
+--------------+------------------------+--------+
```

I want the epic name in the x-axis and results in the y-axis.

Here is my shiny app code.

Ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Bar Chart"),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("")
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(RMySQL)

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 dbname = "mydb",
                 host = "localhost",
                 user = "root", 
                 password = "root")

x_names = c("UnifiedSearch_Pass, UnifiedSearch_Fail, Settings_Pass, Settings_Fail, Map_Overview_Pass, Map_Overview_Fail, Map_Guidance_Pass, Map_Guidance_Fail, RouteBar_Pass, RouteBar_Failm, MainMenu_Pass, MainMenu_Fail, SpeedCameras_Pass, SpeedCameras_Fail, MapManagement_Pass, MapManagement_Fail, AccountManagement_Pass, AccountManagement_Fail, VoiceManagement_Pass, VoiceManagement_Fail, Total_Automated_Tests, Total_Pass, Total_Fail")

loadData = function(){
  dbGetQuery(conn = con, statement = "SELECT Result FROM 2017_8_16;")
}

DETAIL = data.frame(x_names, loadData)

shinyServer(function(input, output){

bar2 <- tapply(DETAIL)
barplot(bar2)

})
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your ui and server logic must refer to same id of the element.
therefore ui code should read plotOutput("someID") which is the container for your plot and server code then creates the plot itself in output$someID = renderPlot({...})

since you are you shiny why not to use the advantage of the interactivity rather than static plots from basic R, 
here you have good introduction to amCharts implementation in R
https://datastorm-open.github.io/introduction_ramcharts/
see below example:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(rAmCharts)

runApp(launch.browser = TRUE,
       shinyApp(
       ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel("Bar Chart"),mainPanel(amChartsOutput("am_barplot"),plotOutput("basic_barplot")))),
       server=shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
         plot.data = reactive({
           table.text = "1 | UnifiedSearch_Pass     |    177
           2 | UnifiedSearch_Fail     |      8
           3 | Settings_Pass          |     57
           4 | Settings_Fail          |      5 
           5 | Map_Overview_Pass      |     90 
           6 | Map_Overview_Fail      |      6 
           7 | Map_Guidance_Pass      |     48 
           8 | Map_Guidance_Fail      |      3 
           9 | RouteBar_Pass          |     48 
           10 | RouteBar_Fail          |      6 
           11 | MainMenu_Pass          |    109 
           12 | MainMenu_Fail          |     12 
           13 | SpeedCameras_Pass      |     17 
           14 | SpeedCameras_Fail      |      2 
           15 | MapManagement_Pass     |     14 
           16 | MapManagement_Fail     |      0 
           17 | AccountManagement_Pass |     12 
           18 | AccountManagement_Fail |      0 
           19 | VoiceManagement_Pass   |     10 
           20 | VoiceManagement_Fail   |      0 
           21 | Total_Automated_Tests  |    624 
           22 | Total_Pass             |    582 
           23 | Total_Fail             |     42"
           plot.data = as.data.table(read.table(sep = "|",text = table.text))
           setnames(x=plot.data,c('SerialNumber','EpicName','Result'))
           return(plot.data)
         })
         output$am_barplot = renderAmCharts({
          expr=amBarplot(data=plot.data(),x='EpicName',y='Result', labelRotation = 90L)
         })
         output$basic_barplot = renderPlot({
           barplot(height=plot.data()[['Result']],names.arg = plot.data()[['EpicName']])
         })
       })
))
```